# Where should Routing and MongoDB Collection code go in a Meteor project?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, iron-router

In my my Meteor project, I finally "did the right thing" and broke out my code from the default single .html and .css and .js (with ".isClient" and ".isServer" blocks) files into separate files in a project structure like this (my project's name is "Scheduler"):

```
Scheduler
        Client (folder)
            main.html (moved the two templates from scheduler.html for the "first page" here)
            main.js (moved the .isClient code from scheduler.js here)
            Templates (folder)
                openExistingSchedule.html (contains a template; will add more later, as the project grows)
        Server (folder)
            scheduler.js (moved the .isServer code here)
```

But where should I put code that belongs neither in "client" nor "server"? Specifically, iron router code such as:

```
Router.route('/platypus');
```

...and MongoDB code such as:

```
Playtpus = new MongoDB.Collection('platypus');
```

Should this go in a "public" folder's .js file, or...???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iirc you're using iron-router. Until you start creating REST endpoints [(docs)](http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/#client-and-server) you can keep your router code under */client* . Your collection definition code (`new MongoDB...`) needs to go under */lib* to be available to both the client and server.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on your router. For example, using `kadirahq:flow-router`, if used as a client only router, should go in `client/`. With fast-render support, it should go in `lib`

The basic rules of loading:

- Anything in `client` or `public` will be loaded into the client, and not the server.
- Anything in `server` or `private` will be loaded in only the server.
- Anything in `lib` will be loaded to both client and server *FIRST*
- Anything in any other folder will be loaded to both client and server.

Generally, you'd want to put it in `lib` so it loads first.